# Is there a difference in performance between logic in html expression and logic in a class property in an Angular template?

Tags: angular, performance, angular2-changedetection

I know because of Angular change detection strategy it is less performant add functions in the component HTML, as the function will be called for every change detection cycle.

But is there a difference between defining a simple comparison in the template or setting a component property in the class instead and bind to this?

**Case 1:**

Component template defines comparison:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let test of testList">
    <p *ngIf="test.val > 0">Positive</p>
</ng-container>
```

**Case 2:**

Component template binds to class property:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let test of testList">
    <p *ngIf="test.isPositive">Positive</p>
</ng-container>
```

Component class predefines property:

```
{

    @Input() items: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        for (let x = 0; x < this.testList.length; x++) {
            this.testList[x]['isPositive'] = this.testList[x].val > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Option D, none of the above 

Answer (score 0):

I would go with none of the above.
But if you really have to do it, then do it in the Component.

For your case, it doesn't matter, but when you're calling a method to get a value:
e.g.: `*ngIf="isPositive(test)"`, this would be very bad for performance as it will be called even on element hover.